# How to simplify the expression below

Tags: summation

I was stuck with simplifying this expression:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n}} \log (i) $$

I was told that it equals to $$n\times2^{n}$$
Thank you for your help!

Comment: $\log((2^n)!) $

Comment: It is not $n2^n$ even for $n=1$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

1. $\log(a) + \log(b) = \log(a\cdot b)$
2. $1\cdot 2\cdot\cdots\cdot (t - 1)\cdot t = t!$
3. [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation): $\ln (r!) \simeq r\ln (r)$
4. $\log_c c = 1$